# How can I view the entire name of a file when browsing through files/folders in Word for Mac 2011, without having to open each file?

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, filenames

Probably a stupid question, but I just recently purchased a MacBook Pro, with which I use Office for Mac 2011.  It's great, but when I am browsing for a file to open, I sometimes have difficulty knowing which file I am about to open - that is, if the file has a long name that starts with the same words as another file, I can't easily tell the difference between the two because the rest of the name gets replaced with ellipses.  I thought if I hovered the cursor over the file, the whole name might show up, but that doesn't happen.  Does anyone have a shortcut suggestion?  It is a pain having to open up each file to find out if it's the right one.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking at the Open dialog box, you can adjust the width of the columns in the dialog by hovering the mouse cursor over the boundary between the headings of the relevant columns, then dragging. The settings are "sticky".

So here, I see Columns called "Name" and "Date modified", I click on the boundary between those two column headings and drag to the right.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I hadn't thought of that because I prefer to view the icon versions of files and folders.  Any ideas in that case?

Comment: In snow leopard (I think) and later, you can press space for a "quick look" at the current file, which should show the full file name in the title bar. Best I can suggest right now!

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that either…very helpful; thank you for both responses!

Comment: I didn't know that either, so a useful question for me :-)